# PHP upload picture with large dimensions

Tags: php

Can someone please help me, almost all of may hair has gone now. I had an issue trying to upload large pictures to a site. I've since fixed this and everything seems to be working ok. I've tested my script with 10Mb+ JPEG files and all appears perfect. However, i have just tried uploading a JPEG from someones phone (4.9Mb) and I get a 500 error. Looking at the picture in PS, the dimensions are 1054px wide by 1874px high at 72dpi. Could anyone help me as to why this is a problem and how I get around it? If I make the picture smaller (700px wide), it uploads fine?

Has anyone had the same problem? Here is my code below that rotates the image (as some from a phone were coming out upside down once uploaded) and then resizes the large files so they are easy to store. All pictures i've tested it with seem to work... apart from this portrait one thats stupidly wide! Someone please help!

```
$file_name = $_FILES['newPicture']['tmp_name'];

correctImageOrientation($file_name);
AdjustPicSize($file_name);


function correctImageOrientation($file_name) {
  if (function_exists('exif_read_data')) {
    $exif = exif_read_data($file_name);
    if($exif && isset($exif['Orientation']) || !isset($exif['Orientation'])) {
      $orientation = $exif['Orientation'];
      if($orientation != 1){
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_name);
        $deg = 0;
        switch ($orientation) {
          case 3:
            $deg = 180;
            break;
          case 6:
            $deg = 270;
            break;
          case 8:
            $deg = 90;
            break;
        }
        if ($deg) {
          $img = imagerotate($img, $deg, 0);       
        }
        // then rewrite the rotated image back to the disk as $filename
        imagejpeg($img, $file_name, 95);
      } // if there is some rotation necessary
    } // if have the exif orientation info
  } // if function exists     
}


function AdjustPicSize($file_name)
{
    $maxDim = 800;

        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $file_name );
        if ( $width > $maxDim || $height > $maxDim ) {
            $target_filename = $file_name;
            $ratio = $width/$height;
            if( $ratio > 1) {
                $new_width = $maxDim;
                $new_height = $maxDim/$ratio;
            } else {
                $new_width = $maxDim*$ratio;
                $new_height = $maxDim;
            }
            $src = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( $file_name ) );
            $dst = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
            imagecopyresampled( $dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
            imagejpeg( $dst, $target_filename ); // adjust format as needed
        }
}
```

Please be gentle too, i'm a bit new to all this!

Comment: More detail than a 500 error would help the diagnosis. Can you check your PHP log file to see what the actual error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's memory limit issue, you may want to increase it or considering using image magick. GD uses RAM to store data and creat new resources from 5 MB file (in big dimensions) would cost you memory

Comment: Hi ya Trac, thanks ever so much for your reply! Would it definitely be a memory issue, even though I can upload images 3 x the file size?

Comment: It's not about file size, it's file dimensions, a jpeg taken from 20 MEgapixel camera is less than 1MB but it can destroy your memory when handling, try to use Image Magick or check dimensions first before using imagecreatefromjpeg

Comment: Thanks ever so much Trac, i've just up'd the memory and the problematic file seems to go up ok! Thank you! REALLY appreciate it!